# How to rewrite the get variables using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a htaccess file that rewrites the link

```
http://www.example.com/profiles.php?view_user=test
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/profiles?view_user=test
```

---

but i want to rewrite the remaining get variable --

```
profiles?view_user=test
```

to

```
profiles/view_user/test
```

help me out i dont know much of htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the appropriate place in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+profiles\.php\?([^=&]+)=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /profiles/%1/%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profiles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /profiles.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Also make sure you have multiviews turned off:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(profiles)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?$2=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```